# IdentityServer4 with React

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I am new to React, and developing a WebApp, which requires authenticating user via IdentityServer. So this is what i 've done so far :

1. Created a react web app using npx create-react-app.
2. Created a Security service using Identity server which renders my login page.

Where i am stuck :

1. Since i am planning to use redux in my react web app, shall i create a reducer/action for the login operation (i am planning to have them for other operations).
2. How to redirect user to the Authorize/Login page of security service and redirect back to my react app? (Can i use aurelia-oauth or some other plugin ?)

Things i have tried :

1. Have defined route for login page in react app (which will be discarded, since i am going to use login page of security service.
2. Tried making a get request for the login url of security service from react app. (Throws : TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'render' on react-dom.development.js)

Comment: Which library are you using to load your custom login page? I have my own oauth2 provider which has its own Login/Signup pages... But I am unable to find a suitable library to render my provider login page.